# Speed cartesian product function

Tags: java, android

i have write this method :

```
public static int myCount = 0;
public static int findOperation( String[] current, int k) {

    if (k == newListCodelist.size()) {
        myCount++;// this is max possible selection
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            Log.i("sort", current[i] + " ");
        }
        result.add("\n");
        Log.i("sort", "current count: " + myCount);

    } else {
        List<CodeRegistry> code = newListCodelist.get(k).getStatusMessage() .getCodelists().getCodelist().get(0).getCode(); 
        for (int j = 0; j < newListCodelist.get(k).getStatusMessage()
                .getCodelists().getCodelist().get(0).getCode().size(); j++) {

            current[k] = code.get(j).getId(); 
            findOperation( current, k + 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function works correctly, I need to calculate all possible actions of n sets.

**My problem is when this function is to analyze a lot of data. Do you have any advice for implementation to speed it up?**

I was thinking of convertinre the data type `String: "getID ()"` in integer type.
Can I use this function for example to convert:

```
Integer.parseInt ()
```

But it does not work because the id are such so "My_ID" - "My_ID_Two"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Crazy but you could bring your getcode method outside the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand, could you explain better

Comment: Code code = newListCodelist.get(k).getStatusMessage()                    .getCodelists().getCodelist().get(0).getCode(); for (int..; j<code.size();..) { current...=code.get(j)....} so you dont end up doing all those crazy stuff in a loop again and again. Also its not really clear what you are trying to achieve in above.

Comment: Ok now I get it. I made the change but it is still very slow. However, I have said what I try to do "Cartesian Product" I have a list that contains other lists to 'internal values. I need to find all possible combinations.

Comment: update your code above in your question and explain what is that huge line of getcode doing and whats the structure of each object.